# Downloading multiple pictures with Picasso

Tags: android, picasso

I'm trying to download multiple pictures using picasso. here's my code:

```
for(int i=1; i <=20; i++){
    String url = img_url + i + "/profile.jpg";
    String img_dir = img_dir + i;
    Picasso.with(this).load(url).into(picassoImageTarget(getApplicationContext(),img_dir, img_name));

}
```

Url of the site looks like this:

```
site.com/img/equipment/1/profile.jpg, 
site.com/img/equipment/2/profile.jpg, 
site.com/img/equipment/3/profile.jpg
```

and so on ...

i tried

```
Picasso.with(this).load(url).into(picassoImageTarget(getApplicationContext(),img_dir, img_name));
```

without the for loop and it is working. images are not download when i place it inside the loop.

here's my Target

```
private Target picassoImageTarget(Context context, final String imageDir, final String imageName) {
    Log.d("picassoImageTarget", " picassoImageTarget");
    ContextWrapper cw = new ContextWrapper(context);
    final File directory = cw.getDir(imageDir, Context.MODE_PRIVATE); // path to /data/data/yourapp/app_imageDir
    return new Target() {
        @Override
        public void onBitmapLoaded(final Bitmap bitmap, Picasso.LoadedFrom from) {
            new Thread(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    final File myImageFile = new File(directory, imageName); // Create image file
                    FileOutputStream fos = null;
                    try {
                        fos = new FileOutputStream(myImageFile);
                        bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, fos);
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    } finally {
                        try {
                            fos.close();
                        } catch (IOException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    }
                   Log.i("image", "image saved to >>>" + myImageFile.getAbsolutePath());

                }
            }).start();
        }

        @Override
        public void onBitmapFailed(Drawable errorDrawable) {
        }
        @Override
        public void onPrepareLoad(Drawable placeHolderDrawable) {
            if (placeHolderDrawable != null) {}
        }
    };
}
```

please help. thanks.

Comment: do you see any errors in log file? Have you confirmed that `url` value in your loop is as expected?

Comment: yes i'm pretty sure the url value is correct. The log file shows no errors but the picture still won't download.

Comment: i have tried making a Target class but it is still not downloading. it is making the directories but not downloading the pictures.

Comment: Targets are held in WeakReferences. They will be gc'd unless you hold a reference to them.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Targets are held in WeakReferences.](https://square.github.io/picasso/2.x/picasso/com/squareup/picasso/RequestCreator.html#into-com.squareup.picasso.Target-)

You need to hold a reference to the Targets you want to keep to prevent them from being garbage collected.

Maybe your code would look something like:

```
final class MyLoader {
  final ArrayList<Target> targets = new ArrayList<>(20);
  void load(...) {
    for(...) {
      Target target = picassoImageTarget(...);
      targets.add(target);
      picasso.load(...).into(target); // TODO: Maybe remove from list when complete.
    }
  }
}
```